# How to convert np.array into pd.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I have loaded the 'load_iris' toy dataset in the Scikit learn library.

```
{'data': array([[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2],
    [4.9, 3. , 1.4, 0.2],
    [4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2],
    [4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2],
    [5. , 3.6, 1.4, 0.2],
    [5.4, 3.9, 1.7, 0.4],
    [4.6, 3.4, 1.4, 0.3],
    [5. , 3.4, 1.5, 0.2],
    [4.4, 2.9, 1.4, 0.2],
    [4.9, 3.1, 1.5, 0.1],
    [5.4, 3.7, 1.5, 0.2],
    [4.8, 3.4, 1.6, 0.2],
    [4.8, 3. , 1.4, 0.1],
    [4.3, 3. , 1.1, 0.1],
    [5.8, 4. , 1.2, 0.2],
    [5.7, 4.4, 1.5, 0.4],
    [5.4, 3.9, 1.3, 0.4],
    [5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.3],
    [5.7, 3.8, 1.7, 0.3],
    [5.1, 3.8, 1.5, 0.3],
    [5.4, 3.4, 1.7, 0.2],
    [5.1, 3.7, 1.5, 0.4],
    [4.6, 3.6, 1. , 0.2],
    [5.1, 3.3, 1.7, 0.5],
    [4.8, 3.4, 1.9, 0.2],
    [5. , 3. , 1.6, 0.2],
    [5. , 3.4, 1.6, 0.4],
    [5.2, 3.5, 1.5, 0.2],
    [5.2, 3.4, 1.4, 0.2],
    [4.7, 3.2, 1.6, 0.2],
    [4.8, 3.1, 1.6, 0.2],
    [5.4, 3.4, 1.5, 0.4],
    [5.2, 4.1, 1.5, 0.1],
    [5.5, 4.2, 1.4, 0.2],
    [4.9, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2],
    [5. , 3.2, 1.2, 0.2],
    [5.5, 3.5, 1.3, 0.2],
    [4.9, 3.6, 1.4, 0.1],
    [4.4, 3. , 1.3, 0.2],
    [5.1, 3.4, 1.5, 0.2],
    [5. , 3.5, 1.3, 0.3],
    [4.5, 2.3, 1.3, 0.3],
    [4.4, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2],
    [5. , 3.5, 1.6, 0.6],
    [5.1, 3.8, 1.9, 0.4],
    [4.8, 3. , 1.4, 0.3],
    [5.1, 3.8, 1.6, 0.2],
    [4.6, 3.2, 1.4, 0.2],
    [5.3, 3.7, 1.5, 0.2],
    [5. , 3.3, 1.4, 0.2],
    [7. , 3.2, 4.7, 1.4],
    [6.4, 3.2, 4.5, 1.5],
    [6.9, 3.1, 4.9, 1.5],
    [5.5, 2.3, 4. , 1.3],
    [6.5, 2.8, 4.6, 1.5],
    [5.7, 2.8, 4.5, 1.3],
    [6.3, 3.3, 4.7, 1.6],
    [4.9, 2.4, 3.3, 1. ],
    [6.6, 2.9, 4.6, 1.3],
    [5.2, 2.7, 3.9, 1.4],
    [5. , 2. , 3.5, 1. ],
    [5.9, 3. , 4.2, 1.5],
    [6. , 2.2, 4. , 1. ],
    [6.1, 2.9, 4.7, 1.4],
    [5.6, 2.9, 3.6, 1.3],
    [6.7, 3.1, 4.4, 1.4],
    [5.6, 3. , 4.5, 1.5],
    [5.8, 2.7, 4.1, 1. ],
    [6.2, 2.2, 4.5, 1.5],
    [5.6, 2.5, 3.9, 1.1],
    [5.9, 3.2, 4.8, 1.8],
    [6.1, 2.8, 4. , 1.3],
    [6.3, 2.5, 4.9, 1.5],
    [6.1, 2.8, 4.7, 1.2],
    [6.4, 2.9, 4.3, 1.3],
    [6.6, 3. , 4.4, 1.4],
    [6.8, 2.8, 4.8, 1.4],
    [6.7, 3. , 5. , 1.7],
    [6. , 2.9, 4.5, 1.5],
    [5.7, 2.6, 3.5, 1. ],
    [5.5, 2.4, 3.8, 1.1],
    [5.5, 2.4, 3.7, 1. ],
    [5.8, 2.7, 3.9, 1.2],
    [6. , 2.7, 5.1, 1.6],
    [5.4, 3. , 4.5, 1.5],
    [6. , 3.4, 4.5, 1.6],
    [6.7, 3.1, 4.7, 1.5],
    [6.3, 2.3, 4.4, 1.3],
    [5.6, 3. , 4.1, 1.3],
    [5.5, 2.5, 4. , 1.3],
    [5.5, 2.6, 4.4, 1.2],
    [6.1, 3. , 4.6, 1.4],
    [5.8, 2.6, 4. , 1.2],
    [5. , 2.3, 3.3, 1. ],
    [5.6, 2.7, 4.2, 1.3],
    [5.7, 3. , 4.2, 1.2],
    [5.7, 2.9, 4.2, 1.3],
    [6.2, 2.9, 4.3, 1.3],
    [5.1, 2.5, 3. , 1.1],
    [5.7, 2.8, 4.1, 1.3],
    [6.3, 3.3, 6. , 2.5],
    [5.8, 2.7, 5.1, 1.9],
    [7.1, 3. , 5.9, 2.1],
    [6.3, 2.9, 5.6, 1.8],
    [6.5, 3. , 5.8, 2.2],
    [7.6, 3. , 6.6, 2.1],
    [4.9, 2.5, 4.5, 1.7],
    [7.3, 2.9, 6.3, 1.8],
    [6.7, 2.5, 5.8, 1.8],
    [7.2, 3.6, 6.1, 2.5],
    [6.5, 3.2, 5.1, 2. ],
    [6.4, 2.7, 5.3, 1.9],
    [6.8, 3. , 5.5, 2.1],
    [5.7, 2.5, 5. , 2. ],
    [5.8, 2.8, 5.1, 2.4],
    [6.4, 3.2, 5.3, 2.3],
    [6.5, 3. , 5.5, 1.8],
    [7.7, 3.8, 6.7, 2.2],
    [7.7, 2.6, 6.9, 2.3],
    [6. , 2.2, 5. , 1.5],
    [6.9, 3.2, 5.7, 2.3],
    [5.6, 2.8, 4.9, 2. ],
    [7.7, 2.8, 6.7, 2. ],
    [6.3, 2.7, 4.9, 1.8],
    [6.7, 3.3, 5.7, 2.1],
    [7.2, 3.2, 6. , 1.8],
    [6.2, 2.8, 4.8, 1.8],
    [6.1, 3. , 4.9, 1.8],
    [6.4, 2.8, 5.6, 2.1],
    [7.2, 3. , 5.8, 1.6],
    [7.4, 2.8, 6.1, 1.9],
    [7.9, 3.8, 6.4, 2. ],
    [6.4, 2.8, 5.6, 2.2],
    [6.3, 2.8, 5.1, 1.5],
    [6.1, 2.6, 5.6, 1.4],
    [7.7, 3. , 6.1, 2.3],
    [6.3, 3.4, 5.6, 2.4],
    [6.4, 3.1, 5.5, 1.8],
    [6. , 3. , 4.8, 1.8],
    [6.9, 3.1, 5.4, 2.1],
    [6.7, 3.1, 5.6, 2.4],
    [6.9, 3.1, 5.1, 2.3],
    [5.8, 2.7, 5.1, 1.9],
    [6.8, 3.2, 5.9, 2.3],
    [6.7, 3.3, 5.7, 2.5],
    [6.7, 3. , 5.2, 2.3],
    [6.3, 2.5, 5. , 1.9],
    [6.5, 3. , 5.2, 2. ],
    [6.2, 3.4, 5.4, 2.3],
    [5.9, 3. , 5.1, 1.8]]),
 'target': array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]),
 

'frame': None,
 'target_names': array(['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica'], dtype='<U10'),
 'DESCR': '.. _iris_dataset:\n\nIris plants dataset\n--------------------\n\n**Data Set Characteristics:**\n\n    :Number of Instances: 150 (50 in each of three classes)\n    :Number of Attributes: 4 numeric, predictive attributes and the class\n    :Attribute Information:\n        - sepal length in cm\n        - sepal width in cm\n        - petal length in cm\n        - petal width in cm\n        - class:\n                - Iris-Setosa\n                - Iris-Versicolour\n                - Iris-Virginica\n                \n    :Summary Statistics:\n\n    ============== ==== ==== ======= ===== ====================\n                    Min  Max   Mean    SD   Class Correlation\n    ============== ==== ==== ======= ===== ====================\n    sepal length:   4.3  7.9   5.84   0.83    0.7826\n    sepal width:    2.0  4.4   3.05   0.43   -0.4194\n    petal length:   1.0  6.9   3.76   1.76    0.9490  (high!)\n    petal width:    0.1  2.5   1.20   0.76    0.9565  (high!)\n    ============== ==== ==== ======= ===== ====================\n\n    :Missing Attribute Values: None\n    :Class Distribution: 33.3% for each of 3 classes.\n    :Creator: R.A. Fisher\n    :Donor: Michael Marshall (MARSHALL%PLU@io.arc.nasa.gov)\n    :Date: July, 1988\n\nThe famous Iris database, first used by Sir R.A. Fisher. The dataset is taken\nfrom Fisher\'s paper. Note that it\'s the same as in R, but not as in the UCI\nMachine Learning Repository, which has two wrong data points.\n\nThis is perhaps the best known database to be found in the\npattern recognition literature.  Fisher\'s paper is a classic in the field and\nis referenced frequently to this day.  (See Duda & Hart, for example.)  The\ndata set contains 3 classes of 50 instances each, where each class refers to a\ntype of iris plant.  One class is linearly separable from the other 2; the\nlatter are NOT linearly separable from each other.\n\n.. topic:: References\n\n   - Fisher, R.A. "The use of multiple measurements in taxonomic problems"\n     Annual Eugenics, 7, Part II, 179-188 (1936); also in "Contributions to\n     Mathematical Statistics" (John Wiley, NY, 1950).\n   - Duda, R.O., & Hart, P.E. (1973) Pattern Classification and Scene Analysis.\n     (Q327.D83) John Wiley & Sons.  ISBN 0-471-22361-1.  See page 218.\n   - Dasarathy, B.V. (1980) "Nosing Around the Neighborhood: A New System\n     Structure and Classification Rule for Recognition in Partially Exposed\n     Environments".  IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine\n     Intelligence, Vol. PAMI-2, No. 1, 67-71.\n   - Gates, G.W. (1972) "The Reduced Nearest Neighbor Rule".  IEEE Transactions\n     on Information Theory, May 1972, 431-433.\n   - See also: 1988 MLC Proceedings, 54-64.  Cheeseman et al"s AUTOCLASS II\n     conceptual clustering system finds 3 classes in the data.\n   - Many, many more ...',
 'feature_names': ['sepal length (cm)',
  'sepal width (cm)',
  'petal length (cm)',
  'petal width (cm)'],
 'filename': 'iris.csv',
 'data_module': 'sklearn.datasets.data'}
```

I wish to convert this dataset, which is in array form into a data frame but am unable to do so with the following command, which return the first 4 columns completely filled with Nan

```
y = pd.DataFrame(datasets.load_iris(),columns = ['sepal length (cm)','sepal width (cm)','petal length (cm)','petal width (cm)','target'])
```

The command gives the following table, which is not correct

```
    sepal length (cm)   sepal width (cm)    petal length (cm)   petal width (cm)    target
0   NaN NaN NaN NaN 0
1   NaN NaN NaN NaN 0
2   NaN NaN NaN NaN 0
3   NaN NaN NaN NaN 0
4   NaN NaN NaN NaN 0
... ... ... ... ... ...
145 NaN NaN NaN NaN 2
146 NaN NaN NaN NaN 2
147 NaN NaN NaN NaN 2
148 NaN NaN NaN NaN 2
149 NaN NaN NaN NaN 2
```

How to do it?
How to get data correctly converted from np.array into pd.DataFrame

Comment: Answer has already been given. For the sake of completion to get data converted from np.array to df you can check out the following `iris = datasets.load_iris(); pd.DataFrame(iris.data,columns=iris.feature_names)`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `as_frame=True` option:

```
df = datasets.load_iris(as_frame=True)['data']
```

output:

```
     sepal length (cm)  sepal width (cm)  petal length (cm)  petal width (cm)
0                  5.1               3.5                1.4               0.2
1                  4.9               3.0                1.4               0.2
2                  4.7               3.2                1.3               0.2
3                  4.6               3.1                1.5               0.2
4                  5.0               3.6                1.4               0.2
..                 ...               ...                ...               ...
145                6.7               3.0                5.2               2.3
146                6.3               2.5                5.0               1.9
147                6.5               3.0                5.2               2.0
148                6.2               3.4                5.4               2.3
149                5.9               3.0                5.1               1.8

[150 rows x 4 columns]
```

If you also want the target:

```
iris = datasets.load_iris(as_frame=True)
df = iris['data']
df['target'] = iris['target']
```

output:

```
     sepal length (cm)  sepal width (cm)  petal length (cm)  petal width (cm)  target
0                  5.1               3.5                1.4               0.2       0
1                  4.9               3.0                1.4               0.2       0
2                  4.7               3.2                1.3               0.2       0
3                  4.6               3.1                1.5               0.2       0
4                  5.0               3.6                1.4               0.2       0
..                 ...               ...                ...               ...     ...
145                6.7               3.0                5.2               2.3       2
146                6.3               2.5                5.0               1.9       2
147                6.5               3.0                5.2               2.0       2
148                6.2               3.4                5.4               2.3       2
149                5.9               3.0                5.1               1.8       2
```